# In Linux how do you make a command run in the background without it outputting to the screen?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, background-process

I know this sounds like a silly question at first glance, but I've tried everything.
I want to execute the command arpspoof in the Kali Linux terminal but I do not want to see the endless output.

First I try this:

```
arpspoof -t 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 >/dev/null
```

And it still outputs to the screen.
Then I try this:

```
arpspoof -t 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 & >/dev/null
```

And it still outputs to the screen.
Then I add another one at the end:

```
arpspoof -t 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 & >/dev/null &
```

And it still outputs to the freakin screen.

Comment: `arpspoof -t 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2   2>&1 > /dev/null &` in bash shell but this is the wrong forum.  Try "Unix & Linux" next time.

Comment: What does that do? Also entered it and there's still output

Comment: This redirects `stderr` to `stdout` before being redirected to `/dev/null`.  Thought you might be getting output from `stderr`.  Could also just try `&>` but don't hold your breath.

Comment: Well I wrote it and I still get output :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
arpspoof -t 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null &
```

where:

`arpspoof -t 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2` is your command

`2>/dev/null` redirects standard error (STDERR) to the "bit bucket"

`1>/dev/null` redirects standard out (STDOUT) to the "bit bucket"

`&` sets the entire command line to run in the background

This line of code is more verbose and *perhaps* clearer to understand.

Comment: @TobySpeight - as you suggested, I added an explanation.  Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat redundant answer but I prefer the format:

```
arpspoof -t 10.1.1.1 10.1.1.2 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Be sure that you don't have background processes still running (therefore still writing to the console/screen) from previous attempts to redirect the output.